# Difference between Android programming architecture and iOS programming architecture

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Throughout Google search some people has told that Android architecture is MVC just like in iOS. But I couldn't feel the separate Model concept in Android. What is the design pattern behind Android design? And what are the main differences in case of programming concept (not IDE, language)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well lets see what we have on both sides:

**iOS:**

- UIViewController
- UIView
- Your stuff (models and other)

**Android:**

- Activity
- View
- Your stuff (models and other)

If you don't know already, `Activity` is the equivalent of `UIViewController` in *Android*.

Given that we know that you can now draw the line for yourself and see that in fact both platforms do work in the same manner from the **MVC** point of view but that can't stop you implement you project's architecture as you think it's the best for you.

Of course the low level implementation and logic in some cases are pretty different on both platforms though.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that Android's architecture is more MVVM than MVC. But I'm also very new to all of this so don't take it for granted. Another opinion on this would be nice!